# Redirecting standard output using Shell()

Tags: vb.net, stdout

I am writing an application, where I have to invoke php.exe interpreter and send output to file. I know that it might be more convenient using `process` class, but I have to use `Shell()`

I tried:

```
 Shell("D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe " & file & " > tmp.html")
```

and:

```
 Shell("cmd.exe |D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe " & file & " > tmp.html")
```

but both prints output instead. How can I use `Shell` and redirect output to file?

Comment: No that's not possible. The function does the following: `Runs an executable program and returns an integer containing the program's process ID if it is still running.` I am curious why you cannot use `Process`?

Comment: Because I am not using pure implementaion of Vb, where process is unavaliable

Comment: If you are not using the .NET framework, you shouldn't tag it VB.NET. Tag it with for example VB6 (if you are using it).

Comment: I am using .net framework, but process is blocked.

Comment: The `Shell` function creates a process under the hood as well... It seems very strange to me that `Process` is blocked (because it is part of `System.dll`).

Comment: @Styxxy, it is strange, but true. However I found a solution - check answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created bat file containing:

```
D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe %1 > tmp.html
```

And then invoked it by:

```
Shell("php.bat " & file)
```